# Trying to auto-create subtasks based off of checkboxes. Subtask will not get created but there are no errors being collected

Tags: java, groovy, jira

I'm working on a JIRA project and one of the things I need to do is auto-create subtasks based on selected checkboxes in the initial issue creation. All the values are getting properly input however the subtask will not be made and there's no errors to check. I put in error collection is the subtask creation validation result came back false, but it's not reporting any errors when I run the code.

What am I missing?

```
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue
import com.atlassian.jira.bc.issue.IssueService
import com.atlassian.jira.bc.issue.IssueService.CreateValidationResult
import com.atlassian.jira.bc.issue.IssueService.IssueResult
import com.atlassian.jira.util.ImportUtils
import com.atlassian.jira.workflow.WorkflowTransitionUtil;
import com.atlassian.jira.workflow.WorkflowTransitionUtilImpl;
import com.atlassian.jira.util.JiraUtils;
import com.atlassian.jira.project.Project
import java.lang.Boolean;
import com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.CustomField;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.CustomFieldManager;
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.user.ApplicationUser
import com.atlassian.crowd.embedded.api.User
import com.atlassian.jira.security.JiraAuthenticationContext
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueInputParameters
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueInputParametersImpl
import com.atlassian.jira.config.SubTaskManager

def customFieldManager = ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager() 
def issueFactory = ComponentAccessor.getIssueFactory()
def issueManager = ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager() 
def cfsubTasks = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjectByName("CRCs Needed")
def checkboxTypeIDs = ['Endpoint':"11309", "IP/DNS Blocklist":"11311", "Network Signature":"11310", "PCAP Pull":"11306", "Splunk Dashboard":"11305"]
def summaryMap = ['Endpoint':"Endpoint Countermeasure", "IP/DNS Blocklist":"IP/DNS Countermeasure", "Network Signature":"Signature Countermeasure", "PCAP Pull":"PCAP Pull", "Splunk Dashboard":"Splunk Dashboard"]
def subTasks = issue.getCustomFieldValue(cfsubTasks);

SubTaskManager subTaskManager = ComponentAccessor.getSubTaskManager()
IssueService issueService = ComponentAccessor.getIssueService();
Project project = issue.getProjectObject();
Long issueId = issue.getId()
JiraAuthenticationContext authenticationContext = ComponentAccessor.getOSGiComponentInstanceOfType(JiraAuthenticationContext.class);
Object userObject = authenticationContext.getUser()
User user = userObject instanceof ApplicationUser ? ((ApplicationUser) userObject).getDirectoryUser() : (User) userObject;

subTasks.each(){
    def key = it.toString()
    IssueInputParameters inputParameters = issueService.newIssueInputParameters()
    inputParameters.setProjectId(project.getId())
    inputParameters.setSummary(summaryMap[key])
    inputParameters.setIssueTypeId(checkboxTypeIDs[key])
    inputParameters.setReporterId(user.getName())
    inputParameters.setApplyDefaultValuesWhenParameterNotProvided(true)

    CreateValidationResult createSubTaskValidationResult = issueService.validateSubTaskCreate(userObject, issueId, inputParameters)
    if (!createSubTaskValidationResult.isValid()) {
            Collection<String> errors = createSubTaskValidationResult.getErrorCollection().getErrorMessages();
            log.error("Sub-task cannot be created due to following reasons: " + errors);
            return;
    } else {
            IssueResult issueResult = issueService.create(userObject, createSubTaskValidationResult)
            Issue subTask = issueResult.getIssue()
            subTaskManager.createSubTaskIssueLink(issue, subTask, user)
            log.debug("Sub-task " + subTask + " for issue " + issue + " is created");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
else {
        IssueResult issueResult = issueService.create(userObject, createSubTaskValidationResult)
        Issue subTask = issueResult.getIssue()
        subTaskManager.createSubTaskIssueLink(issue, subTask, user)
        log.debug("Sub-task " + subTask + " for issue " + issue + " is created");
}
```

In this piece of code you get an *[IssueResult](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/bc/issue/IssueService.IssueResult.html)* instance when you try to create the issue. The *IssueResult* also has *[isValid](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/bc/ServiceResultImpl.html#isValid())* and *[getErrorCollection](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/bc/ServiceResultImpl.html#getErrorCollection())* methods. You should use those to check if any errors occured during the creation of the issue.